# Input string was not in a correct format. calling TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(time)) in IE on Changing Culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, multilingual, culture

Hi i m using given below method to convert in to string its working fine chrome but in IE its through exception **Input string was not in a correct format.**  at this line

```
 s = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(time));
```

these are values i m passing to it

```
600, 298.8, 65505, 69, 70, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 1840.4, 682, 1040.3
```

in chrome its working but in IE it gives exception on second value when i change the culture to french language  please help me out what is the problem

```
public static String ConvertTimeToString(this string time)   
{

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(time))
    {
        return time;
    }

    TimeSpan s;

    if (time.IndexOf(':') >= 0)
    {
        s = TimeSpan.Parse(time);
    }
    else
    {
        s = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(time));
    }

    return s.ConvertTimeToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The failure is probably in the call `Convert.ToDouble`. Your code probably executes in a CultureInfo that has ',' as decimal separator, but your values use '.'. I would advice you to use `Double.TryParse` using a CultureInfo that has '.' as decimal separator instead:

```
Double value;
if (Double.TryParse(time, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out value))
{
    s = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an `IFormatProvider` when you use `Convert.ToDouble(time)`:

```
Convert.ToDouble(time, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Specifying `CulturInfo.InvariantCulture` specifies a culture that expect floating points written as `1.234` (note the period). The source of your problem may be that you `time` is in the format `1,234` (note the comma). Or maybe it is the reverse: You don't specify an `IFormatProvider` and the current culture of you ASP.NET process uses comma as a decimal separator, but the string provided uses period?

If the decimal point used isn't consistent you should either fix it at the source (not sure what the source is here) or as a last resort you can replace comma by period:

```
Convert.ToDouble(time.Replace(",", ".") , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

However, trying to parse a string and not knowing the what to expect is not the best thing to do.

Comment: Thank you all very much specially Mr. Martin Liversage its working Fine now thanks again

Comment: @Zaq: However, that is not related to the browser the client is using.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it may be, I think. If the ASP.NET app is has `<globalization culture="auto" />` in its config the browser may influence the `CultureInfo` of the executing code.